# Validate a claim with multiple values in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: authorization, asp.net-core-webapi, okta, authorize-attribute

We are using Okta as our IDP and performing authorization using bearer token. Our **scp** claim has the following values

```
"scp": [
    "claim1",
    "claim2",
    "claim3",
    "claim4",
    "claim5"
    ]
```

We are using the following code in our asp.net web api to define a policy for authorization

```
services.AddAuthorization(
    options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(
            "HasClaim1", builder =>
            builder.RequireClaim("scp", "claim1"));
    });
```

We are using the following code to add authorization to our controllers

```
[Authorize(Policy = "HasClaim1")]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
 }
```

The validation fails with the following error message

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService: Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
ClaimsAuthorizationRequirement:Claim.Type=scp and Claim.Value is one of the following values: (claim1)
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You could try with the codes below ,insert a break point and check the claims ontokenvalidated when you debug:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(op =>
{
    op.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
    {
        OnTokenValidated = context =>
        {
            var claims = context.Principal.Claims;
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
    .....
});
```

[image]

So it should be :

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(x => x.AddPolicy("HasClaim1", builder=>builder.RequireClaim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/scope", "Claim1")));
```

For your requirement

Comment: Will try this and let you know, Thanks a lot